# How to set new yAxis data in chart dynamically (highcharts + angular2(4))?

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I have spline chart:

```
  this.chart = {
            chart: {
                type: 'spline',
                zoomType: 'x',
                animation: true,
                marginRight: 10,
                renderTo: chartId
            },
```

How can I add new data ( new lines) after user clicked to some button?

```
private addingAxisData() {
// What should be here?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data can be set for series and not for axis.

Check [this documentation for dynamic interaction with Chart object](https://github.com/gevgeny/angular2-highcharts#dynamic-interaction-with-chart-object) - it shows how new points could be added dynamically.

It's possible to use [setData](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.setData) the same way to set data for whole series.